# Setting ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] from a dict rather than file path

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to set the environment variable from a dict but getting and error when connecting.

```py
#service account pulls in airflow variable that contains the json dict with service_account credentials

service_account = Variable.get('google_cloud_credentials')

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=str(service_account)
```

error

```
    PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>'
```

when reading if I use and point to file then there are no issues.

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=/file/path/service_account.json
```

I'm wondering is there a way to convert the dict object to an os path like object? I don't want to store the json file on the container and airflow/google documentation isn't clear at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Python stringio package lets you create a file-like object backed by a string, but that won't help here because the consumer of this environment variable is expecting a file path, not a file-like object. I don't think it's possible to do what you're trying to do. Is there a reason you don't want to just put the credentials in a file?

Comment: Yeah I've been told not to by the project lead. They don't want the file stored anywhere apart from an airflow variable or connection. Essentially I am creating a KubernetesPodOperator to run a python CLI that uploads to S3 and Google Cloud Storage. They want to set the environment variable for the operator like `env={
        'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS': Variable.get('google_cloud_credentials')`

Comment: Airflow documentation and Google documentation is really unclear.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast would it be acceptable to your lead if you were to mount a RAM disk and store the credentials there? That would mean it's stored in RAM instead of disk, which is where it would be if you put it in a variable (although it'd be visible as a file path, which might be considered more of a security risk).

Comment: Yes, Noone would prefer to put credentials to a file that is inside a repository. There is something called "Secret Manager". The last question "Is there a reason you don't want to just put the credentials in a file?" is quite funny though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it, but the Google documentation is *terrible*. So I wrote [a Github gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisfalter/f9def6c0eb43fd5b7fe0d9cfc3977d44) to document the recipe that I and a colleague (Imee Cuison) developed to use the key securely. Sample code below:

```
import json
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def access_secret(project_id:str, secret_id:str, version_id:str="latest")->str:
    """Return the secret in string format"""
    
    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)

    # Return the decoded payload.
    return response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')


def get_credentials_from_token(token:str)->Credentials:
    """Given an authentication token, return a Credentials object"""
    
    credential_dict = json.loads(secret_payload)
    return Credentials.from_service_account_info(credential_dict)


credentials_secret = access_secret("my_project", "my_secret")
creds = get_credentials_from_token(credentials_secret)
# And now you can use the `creds` Credentials object to authenticate to an API
```

Comment: Can you also share the "authenticate to an API" code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the credentials JSON saved into an environment variable as a string, here's how:

First, encode it with base64. This will help prevent issues of saving the JSON as environment variable value due to special (non alphanumeric) characters present in the JSON.

```py
import base64
with open("credentials.json", "rb") as key_file:
    key_data = key_file.read()
    encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_data)
    with open("encoded.txt", "wb") as encoded_file:
        encoded_file.write(encoded_key)
```

Then, put the contents of encoded.txt to an environment variable, e.g. `BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS_JSON`.

Now, you can read credentials straight from environment variable:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import base64

gcp_json_credentials_dict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(os.environ["BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS_JSON"]))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_json_credentials_dict)
client = storage.Client(project=gcp_json_credentials_dict['project_id'], credentials=credentials)
```

(Last checked with: `Python 3.7` and `google-cloud-storage==1.35.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the service account into the repository is not a good practice. As a best practice; You need to use authentication propagating from the default google auth within your application.

For instance, using Google Cloud Kubernetes you can use the following python code :

```
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient   
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', ])
credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
cluster_manager = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
```